Logout User from axios response interceptor for server-component
Here I have implemented axios interceptors for nextjs 14 application. And need help to logout user if any error occurs and redirect user to '/login' page.
I am attaching interceptors code here.
axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(
  (response) => response,
  async (error: AxiosError) => {
    const originalRequest = error.config;
    let session;
    if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
      // session for client component
      session = await getSession();
    } else {
      // session for server component
      session = await getServerSession(authOptions);
    }
    if (
      error.response?.status === 401 ||
      error.message === "Request failed with status code 401"
    ) {
      if (session && session.refreshToken) {
        try {
          const refreshResponse = await axios.post(
            `${BASE_URL}/v1/auth/refresh-token`,
            {
              refreshToken: `${session.refreshToken}avc`,
            }
          );
          const { data } = refreshResponse;
          console.log({ data });
          if (data.access_token) {
            if (originalRequest) {
              originalRequest.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${data.access_token}`;
              return await axios(originalRequest);
            }
          } else {
            // code to logout user
          }
        } catch (e) {
          
          // code to logout user
        }
      } else {
        // code to logout user
      }
    }
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);

I have tried signOut from next-auth/react but it  works only in client-component request and not able to logout from server-component request.

I think creating a new interceptor file might help, all serverside API requests shall be through this interceptor


import { RedirectType, redirect } from "next/navigation";

const serverinterceptor = async () => {
  let response = {};
  try {
    response = await yourApiCall();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  if (response.status === 401) {
    redirect("/login", RedirectType.replace);
  } else {
    response.data;
  }
};



note: Make the function generic to send & recieve multiple api request.

Thank you for your help. I got some progress but still need to reset session and token for security reason. I can not find any solution regarding this.
